# Meteor two way data binding for form validation

Tags: javascript, data-binding, meteor

I read a lot of resources about Blaze allowing reactive rendering for Meteor 0.8, but I can't seem to find a solution for my simple problem below.

I'm trying to validate my form inputs. For the sake of simplicity, lets say that I just want to change my `{{message}}` when a form is submitted. The approach I have taken in `client.js` is simply giving a new value to the helper variable. This is the way how I used to work with AngularJS, but there seems to be more than simply changing the variable in Meteor. How would I go about this?

```
- index.html
<template name="user">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <p>{{message}}</p>
        <button class="submit" onclick="return false;">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

- client.js
Template.user.message = "";
Template.user.events = {
    'click .submit' = function(){
        Template.user.message = "valid";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you use a reactive variable. I'll use a session variable in this example:

```
Template.user.message = function() {
  return Session.get('userMessage');
};

Template.user.events({
  submit: function() {
    Session.set('userMessage', 'valid');
  }
});
```

Note that `events` takes an object (your code is assigning the click handler rather than making a value in an event map).

Comment: I felt there must be some AngularJS way because handling session variables is a lot more cumbersome. But this is definitely a solution.